# Каким образом можно через js узнать логин и id пользователя яндекс аккаунта?

Tags: javascript, юридические-аспекты

Обнаружил, что если зайти на сайт [ПДД](http://www.pdd24.com/) и посмотреть в куки, то вы там увидите свой логин и ID яндекс аккаунта, если авторизованы на текущий момент в яндексе.
Даже если поменять свой аккаунт, то в куках тоже данные поменяются.

Название кук: `yandex_gid`, `yandexuid` и `yandex_login`

Вопрос, как можно через js получить эти данные ? (мне кажется они с блоков для авторизаций тащат?)

И вообще, законно ли то, что они делают? По сути, они там узнает все почтовые ящики пользователей яндекса.

Comment: Ничего они не получат и не узнают, так же как и тысячи других сайтов с яндекс-метрикой. [Same Origin Policy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) не позволит.

Comment: Где вы их там увидите?